# How can I set specific routes on boot?

Tags: networking, windows-8, static-routes

I have a PC connected to 2 networks. One of the network has a domain that I want to logon to. At boot, these two networks both set a route to 0.0.0.0. This breaks all network traffic on my  box. This makes me not able to log on to the domain.

The first thing I do after I boot is run the following commands

```
route change 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.1
route add 10.0.0.0 mask 255.0.0.0 10.0.1.1
```

This routes all domain-internal traffic through the correct NIC and all internet-traffic through the other NIC. Is there any way to set these routes so that they run before I'm asked to log in? This way the computer would find the domain-controller, and I can logon to the domain.

Answer (score 0):

Would a Computer Script help?

Create your 'route' script in a batch file, VBS or PowerShell

Launch gpedit.msc (remember the .msc)

Computer (Not user)
  Windows Setttings
    Scripts 
      Startup

Press Add, and wire-up your script to computer startup.